# Does the default MVC security utilize the same security as ASP.NEt

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication

I am converting a personal site over to MVC 2 and I have been using Forms Authentication against a SQL Server DB. Curious if the standard MVC 2 template will just automatically work if I upload it to the server. I have added the connection string to the web.config. I'm thinking it will work but wanted to see if anyone's done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should work fine because Forms Authentication is not exclusive for ASP.NET Webforms.